# why does changing font size with <input type=submit button error out?

Tags: jquery

I started studying jQuery yesterday by doing [tutorials](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810&feature=plcp)
well I'm on tutorial [28](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jPF0h6AryfY&feature=autoplay&list=PL6B08BAA57B5C7810&playnext=1)/200 now.  This seems like an error so I made a jsFiddles for this.

Sample code: [jsFiddles](http://jsfiddle.net/zLvAr/10/)

**problem:**  why do input buttons not share similar functionality to anchors i.e shrink or increase paragraph size?  I mean I probably would never do this but why does it occur?  Is it even an error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The buttons are actually working (temporarily). The problem is that you're using "submit" as the input type which is causing the form to be submitted and the page re-rendered.

To fix your example, either change the input types to "button" or add an event.preventDefault(); to each of the click handlers (you'll also need to add "event" as an parameter for each handler).

Answer (score 0):

They do, but when you click on a  button it is going to submit your form.  Which is not what you want (I assume).  Try adding a call to preventDefault in your click handler functions.  See my modifications to your jsfiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/zLvAr/10/